# Django more than 2 items in a table, template

Tags: html, django, data-structures, model

I have been searching for a way to make a django template which can show more than 2 values per row in a table,

Let's say I have an class with 5 attributes, and I want these attribute values presented in a table on my HTML page. at first I tried with a dictionary but just 2 of the 5 attributes is not enough.

Lets say my object is like:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='ID') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_column='name')
    yesorno = models.CharField(max_length=9, db_column='yes/no') 
    text = models.TextField(db_column='text') 
    description = models.TextField(db_column='description')
```

Now in a view I call for all these model attributes, in what datastructure should I save everything and how can I put all these 5 attributes in one row per object in a table.
(sometimes hundreds of objects may need to be shown in table (so, 100 rows))

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. Could you post an example what you mean - hardcoded with html? Also you should use "yesorno = models.BooleanField(default=False)" -- and per default you don't need to set "ID". Do you want to use an existing table?

Comment: I used it on a existing database that's why there is the ID.
The yes or no was just an example of information I got in there, it's
actually some different values. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab all the objects (filter accordingly).

As @init3 points out the ID is not required as Django adds that automatically, and `yesorno` should be a Bool.

```
# view.py

model_as = []
for id in ids:
    try:
        model_a = ModelA.objects.get(ID=id)
    except ModelD.DoesNotExist:
        # No model found
        pass
    else:
        model_as.append(model_a)

return render_to_response('template.html',
    {'model_as': model_as},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Loop over the objects in the template and print each variable in whichever column you want.

```
# template.html
<table>
{% for model_a in model_as %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ model_a.ID }}
            {{ model_a.name }}
            {{ model_a.yesorno }}
            {{ model_a.text }}
            {{ model_a.description }}
        </td>
    <tr>
{% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td>No ModelAs to see here</td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, there is one more thing, I can't use the filter option because i have to get the objects one by one with different ID's.

Comment: That will be quite some hit on the database as you'll make one call per object.  I've updated accordingly

Comment: If you’ve got your IDs in an iterable `ids`, couldn’t you do `model_as = ModelA.objects.filter(ID__in=ids)`? (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

Comment: Yep good point.  I think it depends one the quantity of IDs.  I read somewhere that you don't want to to that if there at *too many* as you end up with some GIANT SQL.  Can't give an quantified answer though.  Best to find another way to do it if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that depends on the quantity. In my case it's not very wise to use it I  think.. The Id's requested can go up to 34000. Thanks for the tip tho!